# Jenkins hosting options

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, host

What is the best option (hardware) to host Jenkins. I am willing to use it for open-source and my own needs in local network. Aspects as security, complexly etc. are not considered. I do not see Travis CI, CircleCI or simply using any SaS to host Jenkins as an alternative option.

E.g. I used raspberry pi 4 with 4Gb and Jenkins as Docker Container (wouterds/rpi-jenkins). It did not worked well(slow, laggy).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

containers with jenkins master and slaves are a very good option as you can programatically control upgrades and operations and you are totally independent from the hosting layer. You can build everything on you laptop and move it to cloud or VM within minutes.

There is no universal best solution, and that's why many people love Jenkins as it can adapt to any needs.

Questions:

- what load will you have during build time (what code do you build) ?
- do you need it up all the time / can you afford to shut it down outside office hours ?
- do you need to scale up/down the allocated resources often ?

I use for my personal project a google GCP VM instance that hosts the master and two slaves (one for java and one for mobile apps) . I use docker-compose to control the configuration of the containers. For data persistence, I use a bucket where I copy with a job the whole home folder (not the build workspace). The whole thing fits in the free layer of GCP and I am sure AWS too.

Comment: thanks for suggestion, i will try it. 1. load i would say just average 2. I want to run it at nights as well e.g. automated tests 3. may i ask what resources do you mean?. COuld you give any reference for docs for the e.g. sample you (or similar) use. I.e. GCP VM with jenkins in master slave mode,  setting it up, configuration etc.

Comment: So far I only built one project at a time, java & python code with a n1-standard google instance (2 CPU /8 GB ram). The CPU never went to 100%. In another server, (jenkins running in linux VM), I have 4 CPU /15 GB memory and I saw that it doesn't like more than 1 massive or 2 average projects in parallel.  By massive I mean 5 GB container built with monolith app and by average a standard java microservice container app.

Comment: To have a rough idea, the cost of having a N1 open 24/7 is about 25 usd/month. If you produce big artifacts that need to be downloaded from the cloud, the egress traffic is also billed, so it's cheaper to store them in that cloud. By resources I mean , cpu/memory/disk. In any cloud you can start minimal, scale up by a click and scale down very fast (not instantaneous). You can also write a script to shutdown your instance after the nightly build and in weekends. If you containerize your jenkins, you can experiment with a cloud provider free layer and take you stuff out if you don't like it.

Comment: ok, thanks for infos. Do you know what is the maximum parameter (instances Gb, cpu, memory etc) to use the services for free, I found the pricing on gcp vm confusing?

Comment: That depends on the cloud provider. Amazon AWS has some types of instances in a free tier while Google GPC will give you 300 dollars for 1 year to do whatever you want. I think Microsoft Azure has also a credit option for the first year (like GPC). There are other cloud providers but I know nothing about them.